# New Wifi repeater cannot see _my_ Wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration, repeater

I'm trying to connect to a new Comfast (CF-WR300N, see at botom) as a WiFi repeater.

The irritating thing is that all seems fine, but when I get to the stage of choosing the network to repeat (see capture below), I can see **all** the wireless networks around me, besides **my** network.

**Any suggestions how to debug/solve this problem?**

Both repeater and router are configured for:

- Auto channel
- Mode 11BGN
- Channel Width 40MHz
- Max Tx rate 300Mbps
- Frequency 2.4 MHz

[image: available wifi]
[image: CF-WR300N]

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the repeater and router were configured to auto channel choosing.

Once I manually set the channel, the repeater is able to connect to the router.

Comment: wow.. saved my day :) works like a charm